# sys/time.h timer only runs once

Tags: c, time, timer

I am trying to implement a timer that continuously counts certain amount of time while the software is running. I wrote a dirty code to try how sys/time.h works.
My understanding is that if I set my it_interval struct to a non-zero value, then the timer should start counting again once it's done counting for the value stored in it_value struct.
However, my code stalls. Could someone tell me what I am missing in my code please? Also, I am using Linux.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    struct itimerval timer1;

    timer1.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
    timer1.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    timer1.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    timer1.it_value.tv_usec = 0 ;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer1, NULL);
    printf( "init interval counter: %ld.%ld\n", timer1.it_interval.tv_sec, 
    timer1.it_interval.tv_usec);
    printf( "init value counter: %ld.%ld\n\n", timer1.it_value.tv_sec, 
    timer1.it_value.tv_usec );

    while(1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000000; i++){
            getitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer1);
            printf( "end interval counter: %ld.%ld\n", 
            timer1.it_interval.tv_sec, timer1.it_interval.tv_usec);
            printf( "end value counter: %ld.%ld\n\n", 
            timer1.it_value.tv_sec, timer1.it_value.tv_usec );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output (shortened of course) is:
end interval counter: 5.0
end value counter: 0.8821

end interval counter: 5.0Alarm clock

Process returned 142 (0x8E) execution time: 5.033 s

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps it's got something to do with that lonely and unused `struct sigaction sa;` you got there.

Comment: Oops, I should've erased it. At this moment it's not in my code.

Comment: @HumleBumble Actually, in it lies the answer to your question.

Comment: `time.c:20:27: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]` have anything to do with it?

Comment: @JL2210 hmm I am not getting that warning, although my compiler setting has all Warnings enabled :(

Comment: @PSkocik Sorry for the confusion, I removed the line from my code.

Comment: @HumbleBumble No problem. I kept it in my answer, greatly expanding on it. :D

Comment: @HumbleBumble Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @JL2210 I am using GCC

Comment: What version of the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,...)` causes `SIGALRM` to be sent to the calling process upon timer expiry. `SIGALRM` is a normally deadly signal, whose default disposition is to kill the process.

If you want to prevent your process from being killed by this signal, you need to handle it somehow.

Example (prints EXPIRED from the handler every 100ms) based on your code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void handler(int Sig)
{
    (void)Sig;
    char msg[]="EXPIRED\n";
    ssize_t nwr = write(1,msg,sizeof(msg)-1); (void)nwr;
}
int main(void) {
    struct itimerval timer1;
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,0);

    timer1.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer1.it_interval.tv_usec = 100000;
    timer1.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    timer1.it_value.tv_usec = 100000 ;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer1, NULL);
    printf( "init interval counter: %ld.%ld\n", timer1.it_interval.tv_sec, 
    timer1.it_interval.tv_usec);
    printf( "init value counter: %ld.%ld\n\n", timer1.it_value.tv_sec, 
    timer1.it_value.tv_usec );

    while(1) pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried the code, works just as I wanted my code to. Thank you so much!